# Programatically bind setter to custom dependency property

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I have custom `DataGrid` and in the `OnAutoGeneratingColumn` I create style according what type of the column it is. I have first column with DateTime, which I don't wont to change and then the rest, where I want detect if the value is outside some limits. Now, I want to change the background if the value is outside its limits and I want to be also able to change the colour of the Background. So I made a dependency property and in the data trigger I want to bind the colour to that property. The only problem is, it does not work. Any ideas?

My dependency property

```
public Color BiggerThanMaxBackgroundColor
{
    get { return (Color)GetValue(BiggerThanMaxBackgroundColorProperty); }
    set { SetValue(BiggerThanMaxBackgroundColorProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty BiggerThanMaxBackgroundColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("BiggerThanMaxBackgroundColor", typeof(Color), typeof(MwiTableDataGrid), new PropertyMetadata(default(Color)));
```

The style setting in `OnAutoGeneratingColumn`

```
//Trigger to check if the number is higher than the top limit
DataTrigger higherTrigger = new DataTrigger();
higherTrigger.Binding = new Binding(columnHeaderName)
              {
                Converter = new MoreThanConverter(),
                ConverterParameter = SelectedDevices[this.Columns.Count - 1].maxValue
              };
higherTrigger.Value = "True";

binding = new Binding
              {
                Source = this,
                Path = new PropertyPath("BiggerThanMaxBackgroundColor")
              };
higherTrigger.Setters.Add(new Setter(BackgroundProperty, binding));

Style style = new Style(typeof(DataGridCell));
style.Triggers.Add(higherTrigger);

e.Column.CellStyle = style;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a setter to the style, outside of the Trigger, which will initialize the value of Background.

```
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(BackgroundProperty, Brushes.White));
```

Comment: That wasn't the problem, but it let me to the solution. The problem was, that Background property is of type SolidColorBrushe and I was using Color...